# Fish shell: Shortcut for accept and run command suggestion

Tags: shell, fish

is it possible to create a shortcut such as "Shift+Return" to accept and run the displayed suggestion?

The default key-bindings require pressing the arrow keys, which involve a movement away from the keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, to bind (example) control-y to accept and then execute:

```
bind \cy accept-autosuggestion execute
```

Answer (score 14):

`CTRL-f` should complete the displayed suggestion, after which tapping `Return` will run it.