# Can fish shell's autosuggestion keybindings be customized?

Tags: fish

There are two keybindings to accept a Fish suggestion: `ctrl-f` and right arrow. But these require using pinkies and/or leaving the home row.

I'd rather use something easier to access, like `shift+enter`. Is there a way to configure this? I couldn't find anything in the docs about changing the keybindings.

Comment: Duplicate of this question asked and answered two weeks prior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382012/fish-shell-shortcut-for-accept-and-run-command-suggestion/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They can, by using the `bind` command. Use `bind <sequence> <commands>`, e.g. `bind \cg accept-autosuggestion` to bind it to control-g. Stick it somewhere in config.fish (assuming fish >= 3.0.0).

To find out what sequence your terminal sends for a key combination (these sadly aren't standardized), use `fish_key_reader` and press that combination.

To find out what commands are bound to a particular combo, use `bind <sequence>`. E.g. `bind \cf` will print `bind --preset \cf forward-char` (where `--preset` means that that's the default binding).

However, shift+enter isn't typically possible, simply because it's not sent by the terminal, so it's unavailable to programs running in them.

Comment: Excellent - thank you! And yes, these are **autosuggestions**.

Answer (score -1):

```
bind \e\e  accept-autosuggestion
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.